# C# BlockingCollection Dispose method

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) of `BlockingCollection<T>` class has the following note:

```
Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the 
BlockingCollection<T>. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed 
until the garbage collector calls the BlockingCollection<T> object's Finalize 
method.
```

And [internal implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/99267e7b99cdad8031da216f82b46962c23c383b/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs#L894) of `BlockingCollection<T>` in C# has the following method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Releases resources used by the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection{T}"/> instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">Whether being disposed explicitly (true) or due to a finalizer (false).</param>
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

There is only one call of this `Dispose` with argument `disposing: true` and finalization suppress after the call. But, surprisingly for me, there is no explicit finalizer in the class, and even no call of `Dispose(false)`.
It looks like `Dispose` function is relatively simple and it just removes references to different objects for GC speed up. In this case, GC will do this work for us in the case when we forget to call `Dispose()` explicitly.

Can someone spot the light on the internals of this class? What is the purpose of a method `Dispose(bool disposing)`? Is it common practice to implement this method for .NET core libraries even in cases when it is not needed?

Comment: Wait handles are not free, you overlooked the `m_waitHandle.Dispose();` call it makes inside the dispose method.

Comment: About the message in the documentation, I did not check the presence of a finalizer on this type so I'll take your word for it not being there, but this may be a simple case of copy paste of some documentation, I see the exact same message posted on several types in the documentation.

Comment: The purpose of Dispose is to dispose of the wait handle, and you even linked to the source code that showed this, so I'm not really sure what you're asking about here.

Comment: It's a variation of [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose). With no unmanaged resources it's simplified but still inherited classes may hold unmanaged resources so would need the full dispose pattern implementation while base class provides possibility to be involved in this by implementing this virtual method.

Comment: I understand the purpose of `Dispose()` method in case of its explicit usage (and I'm aware of Disposable pattern). But I'm curious about the case when no explicit `Dispose()` is called. It looks like the documentation says that in this case `Dispose()` will be performed at the finalization stage and presence of `Dispose(false)` method also looks like a confirmation of this hypothesis. But on the other hand there is no explicit finalizer and no calls to the `Dispose(false)` method.

Comment: Nothing is called at finalization stage unless it's explicitly specified in a finalizer, `Dispose` method in your case won't be called during a finalization.

Comment: It is for the usual reason a class has to implement the disposable pattern.  Not to hurry up its finalization, that is exceedingly rare, but to call the dispose method of any of the fields of the class which are disposable.  BlockingCollection uses [two SemaphoreSlim objects](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,61).  In practice is pretty unusual to have to call it since such a collection tends to live for the life of the app, and it is hard to do reliably since you need to be sure all consuming threads are completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) for how to properly implement the dispose pattern is worth a read. However, the answer to your question is that BlockingCollection is not sealed. This means that it can be derived. The reason for the `void Dispose(bool disposing)` is to allow derived classes to properly de-allocate the resources of the base class. So, for example, I could implement

```
class Foo : BlockingCollection<string>
{
  private bool disposed = false;

  ~Foo()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposed)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (disposing)
    {
      // free managed resources
    }

    // free unmanaged resources

    disposed = true;
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

By doing this, when `Dispose()` is called, the BlockingCollection will call `Dispose(true)` on Foo, which will eventually call `Dispose(true)` on BlockingCollection, and you get the benefit that the ~Foo() finalizer is suppressed. If the `Dispose()` method is not called, the finalizer is not suppressed, and it is called, allowing Foo to still deallocate its unmanaged resources.